# Change content of TextView on an item in Custom ListView

Tags: android, listview

I create a Custom ListView, each Item in ListView  has 3 TextView, now I want to change the content of an TextView of item at position 2 (just example). How I can do that?

Thank you!

*EDIT:*

Here is my layout of an item of custom list view:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView      
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:maxHeight="80dp"
android:maxWidth="80dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
android:id="@+id/image"
/>

<LinearLayout 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title Video"
    />
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Title Video"
    />
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/viewcount"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="View Count"
    />
    <TextView 
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/rtsp"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="View Count"
    />
</LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I use this code to get item:

```
final ListView list_playlist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list2);
LinearLayout rowLayout =(LinearLayout)list_playlist.getItemAtPosition(list_playlist.getFirstVisiblePosition()+current_song);
        ImageView image =(ImageView)rowLayout.getChildAt(0);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_song_list);
```

But it's not work!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your row layout for an item in the list is wrapped in a linear layout with 3 textviews. Then if you want to access the 2nd textview of the 2nd item in the list, this would be the code.

```
LinearLayout rowLayout = (LinearLayout)getListView().getItemAtPosition(1);
TextView secondTextView = (TextView)rowLayout.getChildAt(1);
secondTextView.setText("New Text");
```

Comment: Thanks. But what the getListView() mean?

Comment: To implement a list view you use a a ListActivity in android. getListView is a method of list activity which returns the listview.

Comment: Does this line list_playlist.getFirstVisiblePosition()+current_song return a integer? Are you getting any errors in the logcat?

Comment: Yeah, it's return an interger. In Logcat I see this:

09-12 08:12:20.536: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(9536): java.lang.ClassCastException: han.work.youtube.Item_Content
Item_Content is class contain data each item on listview!

Comment: Well that seems to be the problem. your class casting is wrong. Log cat will also give the line number. Try to fix that.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to fix and get back soon :)